# Is $f(x) = x^4 + x^2 + 1$ reducible in $\Bbb Z_2$?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, roots, irreducible-polynomials

Is $f(x) = x^4 + x^2 + 1$ reducible in $\Bbb Z_2$?

My textbook says yes, and gives me the solution of $(x+1)^4$.. I don't quite see how to get there though. Before I checked the solution, I tried plugging in both $0$ and $1$ to see if I could pull out an $x - a$ term, but neither value gives a zero. Any tips?

Comment: Yeah, your textbook is wrong

Comment: @MikePierce can you explain ?

Comment: @c87 Expand $(x + 1)^4$; it does not coincide with $f(x)$.

Comment: Well the solution they gave of $(x+1)^4$ is wrong. You basically explained why that's wrong. See the answer below though as to why the polynomial is still reducible.

Comment: See also: [Let $\mathbb{F}_2 \cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. Is $x^4+x^2+1$ irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_2[x]$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1717907)

Answer (score 5):

Like you've observed, $x^4 + x^2 + 1$ has no linear factors, so if it factors, it is a product of two irreducible quadratics.

An occasionally useful fact is that the only irreducible quadratic polynomial over $\Bbb Z_2$ is $x^2 + x + 1$ (proof: there are only three other quadratic polynomials; check them), so the only possibility in this case is $(x^2 + x + 1)^2$. Either this is or isn't $f(x)$.

Answer (score 3):

*Hint:* A quartic can be reducible without having linear factors.
Compute $(x^2+x+1)^2 \bmod 2$.

Answer (score 1):

Alt. hint:   try in $\,\mathbb{R}[\text{x}]\,$, first: $\,x^4+x^2+1\color{red}{+x^2-x^2}=(x^2+1)^2 - x^2 = \ldots\,$